# While loop with two conditions only checks one

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I have a while loop that is meant to check if a number is a number or that it is 50 or below. At the moment it only runs the loop if it is 51 or more; not if it is NaN! To clarify, it needs to stay in the loop whilst `midday` is above 50 or NaN.

```
var midday = prompt("Enter midday temperature for day " + pn);
midday = parseFloat(midday);

while (Number.isNaN(midday) === false || midday > 50) {
   //validate that the number is w/n an expected range. 
   //No minimum value as not expecting excessivly low input 
   alert("You entered a out out range or incorrect number")

   var midday = prompt("Enter midday temperature for day " + pn);
   midday = parseFloat(midday);
};
```

Comment: Your NaN check is backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this instead of Number.isNaN():

```
typeof(midday) === 'number'
```

isNaN() doesn't check if the var is a number, it checks if the var can be converted to a number who isn't a NaN, so, if you ended up with a scenario like this:

```
isNaN('')
```

You would get that '' is not a NaN, breaking your code...

More about: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Answer (score 3):

I changed the while condition from `Number.isNaN(midday) === false || midday > 50` to `Number.isNaN(midday) || midday > 50`.

The test `Number.isNaN(midday) === false || midday > 50` will return true if midday IS a number. That means that all the numbers will pass this condition.

What you wanted to do is check if midday is not a number Or if its larger than 50

```js
var midday = prompt("Enter midday temperature for day ");
midday = parseFloat(midday);

while (Number.isNaN(midday) || midday > 50) {
//validate that the number is w/n an expected range. No minimum value as not expecting excessivly low input 
alert("You entered a out out range or incorrect number")
var midday = prompt("Enter midday temperature for day ");
midday = parseFloat(midday);
};
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this. It still only stays in the loop if the number is above 50, not if it is NaN

Comment: Than remove the ! Before the is nan

Comment: Updated the answer according to your feedback

Answer (score 0):

isNaN() already checks if it's Not a Number -> You want it to be true. You only need

```
while (Number.isNaN(midday) || midday > 50)
```

Comment: Thanks :) Works but apparently typeof is better to use (see answer above!)

Comment: Since you performed `parseFloat()` on midday it contains either an number or NaN, so you can't run into said problem of `isNaN('')` it might even break in your case since `typeof(NaN)` equals number as well.